# It's my birthday today - how old am I turning?

Tags: riddle

It is my birthday today
Last year I had 5 candles
4 were lit the last was not
But today, I'll light them all

How old am I turning today?

HINT: I am not turning 5 today and...

> Next year I'll have 6 candles, but I'll only light the first

Comment: Hey, welcome to Puzzling! This is a good first puzzle but I highly recommend holding off on giving hints - often you'll find out you don't need them.

Comment: There's 10 kinds of people in the world. Those who understand binary and those who don't.

Comment: @JohannesPille and those who understand Gray code.

Comment: There are 10 kinds of people - those who understand ternary, those who don't, and those who mistake it for binary!

Comment: Funny thing is, I catched this instant aswell, but by catching a hint that actually wasn't  one.... I read "turing" ^^

Comment: We actually did this for my dad's birthday this year (he's a PhD in Comp Sci).

Comment: nice Binary....

Comment: Kudos, @Alexander - well played Sir. However, as an aside, this game never ends: There's 10 kinds of people - those who understand quaternary, those who mistake it for ternary, those who think it's binary and those who think "Why is four ten?"

Comment: @Alexander I always heard this slightly different - *there are 10 kinds of people - those who understand binary, and those who don't -- and those who didn't expect this to be a ternary joke*.  I like it this way because the unexpected part doesn't come until the end.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You're turning

> 11111 (Or 31)! This is because you light your candles in binary: last year you turned 30 (11110) so you only lit the first four candles.

Comment: Oh.. Super fast ! I was typing the same :)

Comment: Ninja'd by the pro!

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴠʏ Me too, but at same time we post; after a few mins we don't :)

Comment: Is the LSB usually 'last' ? I guess the hint defines it, but it took the hint...

Comment: @Lamar: Yes, just like the least significant *digit* is last in base ten.

Comment: Some people (likely many) might call it 'last', others might not, others might see it as arbitrary :)

Comment: What a smart way to save candles!

Comment: I suppose it saves on candles, and breath.

Comment: @LamarLatrell another thing to remember is that the LSB is going to change from year-to-year. If only one candle is changing (as we're told without the hint), it must be the LSB.

Answer (score 40):

Today you are turning

> 31

Since

> you are lighting your candles in binary, $11110 = 30; 11111 = 31; 100000 = 32$

Comment: Ninja'd you again. :P

Comment: @Deusovi Well you got an ^vote from me :)

Answer (score 7):

I've got a different solution, that is very close to the current one, but a little bit different. (and fits of course)

He is turning

> 30. Every candle that is lit stands for 6 years. Every candle that is not lit stands for 5 years. (5 candles lit is 5x6=30) And next year he becomes 31 (1 candle lit, 5 not. 1x6+5x5=31)

Answer (score 0):

You're turning

> 31

Since the analogy is in

> binary and the candles represent face values of the numbers,

you light the first 4

Next year you'll turn

> 32

and only light the first candle and not the other 5.